# Square brackets after dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

was looking at a piece of code and realised I have no idea what square brackets after a dictionary definition mean, and I can't find information on it:

```
my_dict = {
    '1': 1,
    '2': 2
}[potatoes]
```

Is this common knowledge notation? And if so, what is it used for?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called *indexing*. A dictionary maps *keys* to *values*.

You can look up values in the dictionary by their keys.

In your specific case, the dictionary is mapping the string `'1'` to the integer `1` and the string `'2'` to the integer `2`.

Presumably, the variable `potatoes` contains either the string `'1'` or the string `'2'`, so as the end result, the variable `my_dict` will either be the integer `1` or the integer `2`. (It will definitely not be a dict, which means that this is a bad name for the variable.)